# Spring social facebook + spring security permission to email and username scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I want to integrate Spring Social facebook into my application with Spring Security (I use annotation base configurations). All I need is just connect facebook account with my app's account. In simple example I found this:

```
package eu.thinking4u.spring.social.simple.signinmvc.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.ConnectionFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableSocial;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurer;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource;


@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialContext implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Configures the connection factories for Facebook and Twitter.
     * @param cfConfig
     * @param env
     */
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
       /* cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.key"),
                env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.secret")
        ));*/
        /*cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("facebook.app.id"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.app.secret")

        ));*/
        final FacebookConnectionFactory fbcf = new FacebookConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("facebook.app.id"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.app.secret"));
                fbcf.setScope("email");
                cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(fbcf);
       }

    /**
     * The UserIdSource determines the account ID of the user. The example application
     * uses the username as the account ID.
     */
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
                dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator,
                /**
                 * The TextEncryptor object encrypts the authorization details of the connection. In
                 * our example, the authorization details are stored as plain text.
                 * DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION.
                 */
                Encryptors.noOpText()
        );
    }

    /**
     * This bean manages the connection flow between the account provider and
     * the example application.
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

/*    @Bean
    public CanvasSignInController canvasSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, Environment env)
    {
        return new CanvasSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository,
                new SimpleSignInAdapter(), env.getProperty("facebook.appKey"), env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.canvasPage"));
    }*/
}
```

After login in Facebook then we try to fetch user profile like

```
WebRequest request
RegistrationForm dto = new RegistrationForm();
Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);

 if (connection != null) {
            UserProfile socialMediaProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
            System.out.println("DTO EMAIL--->"+socialMediaProfile.getEmail());
            dto.setEmail(socialMediaProfile.getEmail());
            dto.setFirstName(socialMediaProfile.getFirstName());
            dto.setLastName(socialMediaProfile.getLastName());
  }
```

I try to get the email and username but is not working.And first name and last name properly fetched.

Comment: What do you mean with *"I try to configure the email and username scope but is not working."*? At the moment I don't have clue what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the current version of spring social. It's currently being tracked here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SOCIAL-436

In the meantime you can get around this by setting scope via hidden field on your page like this:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/connect/facebook" />" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email" />
    <p>You haven't created any connections with Facebook yet. Click the button to create
       a connection between your account and your Facebook profile.</p>
    <p><button type="submit"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/social/facebook/signin.png" />"/>
    </button></p>
</form>
```